# Изображения со скруглёнными углами

Tags: изображения, css

Уважаемые коллеги, есть ли какой-либо css хак, позволяющий отображать все изображения со скруглёнными углами?

Answer (score 1):

Задай border изображению а потом с помощью border-radius задавай на сколько хочеш округлять должно помоч

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте [Оформление изображений на CSS3](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/css/129313/)

Answer (score 1):

Если картинка фиксированного размера и однородный фон, то можно сделать рамку с скругленными углами и накладывать сверху основной.